# Django search form with multiple filter

Tags: python, django, sqlite

in my Django web site I've got a User page where are listed all the items the User added to the database. There's a search form for the user to search into its own items. The problem is that the search form doesn't work. I'm a little bit confused about how to filter through the database because, first I've filtered all the items in order to show only the ones added by the User logged, and then I should filter through these based on the user input. Hope someone could help me, thanks!

The 'def look()' is what I tried but doesn't work

Views.py

```
class userListView(ListView):
    model = Info
    template_name = 'search/user.html'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        qt = qs.filter(utente=self.request.user)
        return qt

    def look(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('FORM POSTED WITH {}'.format(request.POST['cerca']))
        srch = request.POST.get('cerca')
        if srch:
            sr = Info.objects.filter(srch = Subquery(qt))
            if sr:
                return render (self.request, 'search/user.html', {'sr':sr})
            else:
                return render(self.request, 'search/user.html')
        else:
            return render(self.request, 'search/user.html')
```

user template html

```
<div class="add">
  <div class="posted">
    <div class="head">
      <h2> YOUR LIST </h2>

      <div class="form">
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'user' %}">
          {%csrf_token%}
          <input type="text" name="cerca" class= "form-control" placeholder="  Type Album or Band Name...">
          <!-- <button type="submit" name="submit">Search</button> -->
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>

<!-- Inserire il database dell'utente registrato -->
{% if object_list %}
{% for o in object_list %}
<div class="container_band">
  <div class=album_band>
    <!-- insert an image -->
    {%if o.cover%}
    <img src= "{{o.cover.url}}" width="100%">
    {%endif%}

  </div>

  <div class="info_band">
    <!-- insert table info -->
    <table>
      <tr><th><h3>{{o.band}}</h3></th></tr>
      <tr><td> Anno: </td><td> {{o.anno}} </td></tr>
      <tr><td> Disco: </td><td> {{o.disco}} </td></tr>
      <tr><td> Etichetta: </td><td> {{o.etichetta_d}} </td></tr>
      <tr><td> Matrice: </td><td> {{o.matrice}} </td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

template:

```
<a href="{%url 'searches'%}" >Band: {{ request.POST.srh }}</a><br/>
<a href="{%url 'searches'%}" >Album: {{ request.POST.srh }}</a>
```

Comment: Just implement everything in `get_queryset()`. You only need to return the same queryset filtered by the search parameter. Your method `look` is never called because Django doesn't call a method `look` when running a `ListView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do all of this, you only need to filter your queryset. Also you should change your form's method to GET because you're not making any changes in your database and a `ListView` doesn't normally process POST requests. So change to `method="GET"` in your form tag and:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super().get_queryset().filter(utente=self.request.user)
    q = self.request.GET.get('cerca')  # query parameter because of GET
    if q:
        qs = qs.filter(band=q)  # filter qs further
    return qs
```

I just added a filter for `band` but you can filter further if the search should be on other fields of the `Info` model. e.g. `filter(Q(band=q) | Q(disco__icontains=q))`. I don't know your model so I don't know what your criteria are for a match.

Comment: Perfect, now it works! But what if I have a band and an Album with the same name, and before show one of them let the user decide if he's looking for the band or the album? I made a template with two link, but I don't know what to change in Django (I edited the question with the template)